# Set Publishing Link Field Value on New item form using Javascript

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, javascript, custom-form

I want to set default URL for Publishing Link Column in my SharePoint New Item form using javascript.

Below Field's value should be set to http://a.com/ on form load.

```
<SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff3{$Pos}" ControlMode="New" FieldName="Link" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('i',concat('ff3',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@Link')}" />
<SharePoint:FieldDescription runat="server"   id="ff2description1{$Pos}" FieldName="Link" ControlMode="New" />
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The following function could be used for specifying Publishing Hyperlink column on the client side:

```
function setPublisingHyperlinkValue(fieldInternalName,url,description)
{
    var fieldUrl = $('input[id ^=' + fieldInternalName +  '][id $=UrlFieldUrl]');
    var fieldDesc = $('input[id ^=' + fieldInternalName + '][id $=UrlFieldDescription]');
    fieldUrl.val(url);
    fieldDesc.val(description);
}
```

Example:

1.Open Form page (`EditForm.aspx`) in Edit mode

2.Add Content Editor web part

3.Insert the following code into web part Content in order to set
    default value (`url: http://microsoft.com, desc: MSFT`) for `TargetUrl`
    field:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function setPublisingHyperlinkValue(fieldInternalName,url,description)
{
    var fieldUrl = $('input[id ^=' + fieldInternalName +  '][id $=UrlFieldUrl]');
    var fieldDesc = $('input[id ^=' + fieldInternalName + '][id $=UrlFieldDescription]');
    fieldUrl.val(url);
    fieldDesc.val(description);
}

$(function() {
   setPublisingHyperlinkValue('RedirectURL','http://www.microsoft.com','MSFT');
});
</script>​
```